# Converting StreamingOutput to a string

Tags: java, string, outputstream

I am trying to convert StreamingOutput to string in Java to pass it to another method. It produces the string but it raises the following error later on.

JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem Severe: Problem with writing the data, ContentType: text/plain

What's happening?

```
StreamingOutput stream = method1();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
stream.write(output);
String string = new String(output.toString("UTF-8"));


...
public StreamingOutput method1(...){..}
```

`

Comment: Can we see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This is what I have got. It seems stream.write changes to a byte array and its return type should be text. Don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Try initialising `stream`. So `StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput();`

Comment: Thanks Dan. I forgot to put the method1(). stream gets the stream from method1().

Comment: I am having trouble finding StreamingOutput. Would you mind linking me to the library you are using so that I can test the problem?

Comment: You can take a look at here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html

Comment: Okay after about half an hour of trying to set up the code to run I have completely failed so I cannot test this. But looking at the java docs it accepts [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html?is-external=true) in the `write` method. So try casting `output` to a `OutputStream`. For example `OutputStream output = (OutputStream) new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

Comment: Your modification of the code in the question to match the answer makes this question rather confusing. I would vote your question up if not for that.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you did not properly convert OutputStream to String properly. Please try the code below:

```
StreamingOutput stream = method1();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
stream.write(output);
String string = new String(output.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");


...
public StreamingOutput method1(...){..}
```

Comment: Thanks all. Solved.

Comment: The output was char array, not byte array, so it solved in that way. Thanks anyway.